# Save screenshot (bge) without writing to disk

Tags: python, game-engine

This is a little odd but I need to save a screen-shot as an array (numpy array for eg) without writing to disk. The idea here is to create and then call the array once per frame in an external script so doing this...

```
bge.render.makeScreenshot("frame.png")
```

...and then converting the png takes too long to be feasible mostly due to saving the image (which is something I don't need anyway).

I'm trying to avoid digging into the rasterizer's source as it's completely foreign to me so I figured I'd ask here first. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still can't decide if this is more appropriate here or SO. Kind of in between.

Comment: Look into: `glReadPixels`, combine with this PNG writing function, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19174800/432509

Comment: Thank you! A quick proof of concept worked perfectly. When I have a full script I'll post it as the answer in the off chance that someone else needs to do this.

Comment: you could post the script you ended up with as an answer, I'm sure others would find interesting.

Comment: Did you make it?

Comment: depending on your os, you might have a memory-backed filesystem, for example the debian/ubuntu/linux hosts tend to have a '/dev/shm/' folder which can be used to write files that are backed by memory not hard drive. this is naturally going to couple your scripting to your OS, being able to get the data directly would be nicer.